# Lock Vertices From Being Affected By Gravity

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I have a simple cloth simulation set up that lets it collide with other rigid bodies. It currently falls down because of gravity but I would like to lock the top vertices into position so that it hangs down. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I accidentally had the plane as an active rigid body instead of passive. Changing it to passive fixed my issue.